# Twitter API: How to get the number of people who added tweet to favorites / replied to it?

Tags: twitter

I can easily get the count of retweets via "GET statuses/user_timeline", 
but I couldn't get information for replies and favorites. There is one property in tweet object called "favorited", but it's always empty, I think it's for some other purposes. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only ever know of up to 100 retweets. You can get the number by calling the [GET statuses/show/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid) endpoint. The value is in the `retweet_count` field.

You cannot query other users' favorites. The favorited field will indicate of the authenticated user (who you are authenticated as) has favorited the tweet.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

The new version of API method contains fields `retweet_count` and `favorite_count` (even though you won't see `favorite_count` in the documentation it exists, try it).